# Discovery of norm in PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

We have seen so many norms we need for PDE. For example, for elliptic PDE, we require a continuous version of $C^k$, i.e. $C^{k,\alpha}$. Roughly speaking, under appropriate norm, we could capture the topological information we want. But a question (maybe too vague), how can we know what kind of norm we want in PDE?How can we invent the norm we want? I am just asking for a general idea.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the "right" norm is one that will allow estimates of the solution in terms of the data. You seem to be asking for a way to find that norm without actually developing the estimates. Short of something like divine revelation, I cannot think of a way to do that.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy so for example how holder space was discovered since continuous differential space is not suitable for prior estimate

Comment: Today, we have the advantage that, based on earlier work, we have a sense of what will or will not work. As for the original discovery that Hölder norms and not just $C^k$ norms were necessary to get estimates for elliptic PDEs, my bet is that it was mainly cleverness but also a careful analysis of the fundamental solution of the Laplacian (i.e., the Green's function) and its derivatives, using either its explicit formula or the one in terms of Fourier series.

Comment: Many PDEs originate from physics, and physical intuition can play a very useful role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One striking example, though perhaps considered "antique" by now, is Levi's 1906 use of a (true/correct!) minimum principle in Hilbert spaces, and forming what is now called $W^{1,2}$, to prove a (true/correct!) version of "Dirichlet's principle" (which, in effect, had been asserted for certain concrete Banach spaces, for which it did not actually hold...). Also Frobenius in 1907. As it happened, these *true* theorems, replacing arguably-more-natural Banach spaces by Hilbert spaces, sufficed to recover (=give correct proofs of) most of the classical *applications* of "Dirichlet's principle".

Subsequently, Sobolev's work (and Schwartz') vastly expanded this... not only in the Hilbert-space context. For my own applications, the Hilbert-space context is sufficient and extremely useful.